# How to implement time slot for each questions in my android quiz application

Tags: android

I'm creating a Android Application for quiz, please anyone tell me how to implement time slot for each question and the given time is over then activity should move to next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of countdown timer that gives the user 30 sec to answer.

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

You can use a ViewAnimator to animate the UI ; For example the answered question can slide out to left and the new question slide in from the right.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)?